# Refine/Filter WP_Query Posts with jQuery or Ajax

Tags: wp-query, filters, jquery, ajax

I know this has been asked many many times, but I literally searched for an answer for more than 5 hours without finding anything that drives me in the right direction.

What I'm trying to achieve is something similar to this http://car-insurance.findthebest.com/ where you select terms on the left hand side and these terms are added (in this case they are showed on top of results) with the X next to them to remove those terms from the query.

I have seen many many examples of filtering plugins but most of them are based on the SEARCH and I don't want to have a search.

My example:

Custom Post Type = jobs

Custom Taxonomies = Country, Type, Job Area (like engineers, designers, programmers, etc)

Simple Query getting all the jobs (simplified)

```
    <?php
        $jobs = new WP_Query('post_type=jobs&posts_per_page=10');
        while ($jobs -> have_posts()) : $jobs->the_post(); 
    ?>
    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Anyone that could point me to a tutorial, a plugin, something in the right direction?

Comment: [wecodemore Filterama](https://github.com/wecodemore/filterama) provides that functionality for the admin UI and custom taxonomies. Take it as a starting point then [edit] your question and show what you got.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you might be looking for is combination of a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/ and hooking into `pre_get_posts` if you are looping a list of posts. That plugin is in use on http://theboatworksnews.com/ so you can play with the projects section/filters and see if that matches what you're looking for.